# php online web application

Tags: php, security, hosting

I had this morning a freak problem when I upload a files to my hosting server the server delete some files and say this message "Cette piÃ¨ce jointe a Ã©tÃ© supprimÃ©e, car elle contient des donnÃ©es qui peuvent prÃ©senter un risque de sÃ©curitÃ©."

Comment: seems like hacking issue

Comment: how come ??  but the server delete all file content is that normal

Comment: Ask to your service provider regarding this.

Comment: Apart from the fact that that output string is utf-8 encoded to iso-8859-1 (*"Cette pièce jointe a été supprimée, car elle contient des données qui peuvent présenter un risque de sécurité."*) ... what were you trying to upload... and to what kind of server? That seems to be a standard error message from Exchange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable translation of the text

`Cette piÃ¨ce jointe a Ã©tÃ© supprimÃ©e, car elle contient des donnÃ©es qui peuvent prÃ©senter un risque de sÃ©curitÃ©.`

is

`Attachment not available 
This attachment was removed because it contains data that could pose a security risk`

So according to the message it implies that the file you are trying to upload has some permission issue. Check the permission on that folder for that particular type of files. You must talk to the service provider if the folder has full permission for that type of file. Surely they will be able to help.

As you stated that you can upload the file but then it is deleted, it is seeming that the **file type is not supported by the server**.

Reference :

[Reference 1](https://fr-fr.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=171869389664029)

[Reference 2](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb124399(v=exchg.160).aspx)

Comment: The translation is literally "This attachment was removed because it contains data that could pose a security risk." - its a standard Exchange error message, particularly if using the web access (OWA)...

Comment: Updating my answer. Thank you very much @CD001